# Get your Guru Fixes

Tags: word

> My prefix is my suffix -- hey a circumfix!
>
> My infix is neither dark  nor heavy.
>
> My suffix is my prefix -- yay a circumfix!
>
> It's what Riley did to Puzzling SE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My prefix is my suffix -- hey a circumfix!

> en (or de?)

My infix is neither dark nor heavy.

> light, antonym of both

My suffix is my prefix -- yay a circumfix!

> en (or ed)

It's what Riley did to Puzzling SE.

> Riley ENLIGHTEN(ed) PSE, or Riley DELIGHTED PSE?

Comment: The first suggestion is it!

Comment: lol Riley Delighted PSE

Comment: I'm delightde by the other answer :-)

Comment: Well it's a "circle"fix, per se, looping, so i included it :) @Bass